# Getting some issues using {return this.getAll.get(this.url)} when consuming an API in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to consume an API using Angular and Typescript, my previous knowledge in using API's is mainly in Javascript so I am pretty new to it, however what I have so far is giving me an issue:

I created a new service file:

**growth-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GrowthService {

  url = 'https://uks-tst-tbp-gw.azurewebsites.net/business/getcategories'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllOptions(): any{
    return this.getAllOptions.get(this.url)
  }
}
```

but the line `return this.getAllOptions.get(this.url)` is showing me an error on `.get` saying that

> TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type

However I cannot find a reason as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getAllOptions` from the function `getAllOptions()`itself

probably what you want to do is:

```js
getAllOptions(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.url)
}
```

also as a naming convention you should call function that returns an Observable with a dollar sign at the end i.e. `getAllOptions$(){}`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks thats worked perfectly for me, and yes I agree on the $ part, I'll start doing that

Comment: While I agree with the answer, I disagree on the naming convention part. At the end of the day, it's of course personal preference, but personally I only use the $ at the end of `Observable` variables, not the functions. See Angular's naming conventions for reference: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables